# How to change quarkus log level at runtime?

Tags: logging, quarkus

According to their [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#build-time-configuration), it's possible to override some quarkus configuration at runtime eg log level.
But how to do it ?

For example, in my application.properties I have the log level configured like that :
`quarkus.log.level=INFO`

The [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-core_quarkus-core-quarkus-core) also says there is an environment variable : QUARKUS_LOG_LEVEL related to the log level

Environment variables have [higher priority](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources) than application.properties

So I go inside the pod with `kubectl exec -it blablabla /bin/bash` and I define an env variable like this `env QUARKUS_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG`. The environment variable has been well defined but the log level hasn't been changed... why ? How to do it ?

I ve read : [this link](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/discussions/23133) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63250947/how-to-change-the-log-level-during-runtime-in-quarkus). I don't want to use http client or some extension etc to change the log level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only environment variables present at the start of the application are taken into account as configuration.
Environment variables added after startup, will not have any effect - this is also because Quarkus does not (be design) support dynamic reloading of configuration.